# How to fix 301 permalink redirect for funky structure

Tags: permalinks, redirect

I'm trying to figure out how to redirect the permalink structure for some of my very old WordPress news portals, which are using funky structures that were needed for Google News and old search engines, but now are crap.

For example, I currently have:

```
mynewssite.xcom/2015/03/19/fnw14770_161419.php
```

Where I'd rather have:

```
mynewssite.xcom/pretty-nameo-of-the-article-fnw14770/
```

I would even be okay with this instead:

```
mynewssite.xcom/pretty-name-of-the-article-fnw14770_161419.php
```

My current WordPress permalink structure is:

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/fnw%post_id%_%hour%%minute%%second%.php
```

I need to do a 301 redirect to something like `/%postname%/` or `/%postname%-%post_id%/`, or in a worst case senario, something like this:

```
%postname%-fnw%post_id%_%hour%%minute%%second%.php
```

I don't know how to write rewrite expressions. This is what I currently have now, but it's not working:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/fnw(\d+)_%hour%%minute%%second%.php$ http://floridanewswire.com/?p=$4
```

Answer (score 0):

`%hour%%minute%%second%` won't work in .htaccess, as this is meta information known only to WordPress. Instead, try replacing it with a rule that matches six digits, such as `\d{6}`

Also, you should remove unnecessary capture groups, escape forward sashes and dots, and use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

Here is a fixed and simplified version of your expression:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/fnw(\d+)_\d{6}\.php http://floridanewswire.com/?p=$1
```

You should be able to change your permalinks to a cleaner structure on the *Settings > Permalinks* admin menu and have the old permalinks redirected through this htaccess rule.

Comment: Thanks! Yup, I know the permalink structure won't work in htaccess, was just showing example of the WP permalink setup, since I would need to change that to make the new pretty schema; then the 301 rediretmatch for htaccess. I'm still learning the syntax for the 301 redirect as only had to do full site URL change, not these funky things. I will try this and update -- thank you! :-)